# MySQL: Using sum on a varchar with comma?

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have a column, called net_amount, it contains values like 244,98. Its a varchar column. When I try to sum it using the sum function, it only sums the 244 and skipts the decimal places. I tried casting it to decimal like this:

```
select cast(net_amount as decimal) from mytable
```

This skips the decimal places as well ... any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be storing numbers in a varchar column. Change your table to avoid even more problems.

Comment: the value `244,98`, which part here is the decimal?

Comment: @JW: the ,98 is the decimal place. Its like $244 and 98 cents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use REPLACE to replace comma to dot:

```
SELECT REPLACE('244,98', ',', '.') * 1
```

or you can use CAST like this:

```
cast(REPLACE(net_amount, ',', '.') as decimal(8,2))
```